# Iteration of Variable Values for Max Strategy Profit - Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way in Pine Script to iterate through a range of numbers for multiple variables in a strategy to find the combination with the highest profit without manually combing through every combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. One approach to minimize the number of runs you'll need is to run as many instances of your calcs as you can in one run, when that's possible, so you can at least test a few sets in each run.